# UIButton is not responding when added as footerview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios4, uibutton

My button is not responding to touch events, please find the code snippet as below.

I have added `UIButton` to `UIView` and set the `UIView` to `UITableView's` footerview.

Please let me know and thanks.

```
CGRect tblViewFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, 300);

self.tblViewSettings = [[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tblViewFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]autorelease];
self.tblViewSettings.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tblViewSettings.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
self.tblViewSettings.delegate = self;
self.tblViewSettings.dataSource = self;
self.tblViewSettings.scrollEnabled = YES;

// Set the background color
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIView *buttonView = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 320, 60)]autorelease];
self.signoutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
self.signoutButton.frame = CGRectMake(10,10, 300, 40);
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-large1.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:22 topCapHeight:0];
NSString *strSignOut = NSLocalizedString(@"Sign Out", @"SignOut Button");
[self.signoutButton setTitle:strSignOut forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.signoutButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.signoutButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
[self.signoutButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.signoutButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
[self.signoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(signOutBtnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

buttonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[buttonView addSubview:self.signoutButton];
buttonView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
//[self.view addSubview:buttonView];
self.tblViewSettings.tableFooterView = buttonView;

self.tblViewSettings.tableFooterView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[self.view addSubview:self.tblViewSettings];

-(IBAction)signOutBtnTapped:(id)sender{
}
```

Comment: can you show definition of signOutBtnTapped?

Comment: @rishi : -(IBAction)signOutBtnTapped:(id)sender{

Comment: comment out background image line and shadow offset lines and check.

Comment: are you able to scroll your table?

Comment: one more thing you can by having touches method and see if control goes there?

Comment: actually what the problem is in my code i am setting tableview userinteraction enabled = NO;then i set tabelview footerview userinteraction enabled = YES] but footerview is not userinteraction enabled control.pls help

Comment: why u are disabling the interaction of table view?

Comment: @rishi: because this tableview has so many fields which should not be editable only uibutton which is under footerview should be editable

Comment: then you can disable table view cells instead of disabling whole table view.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at your code and applied it to my project. actually it works. i did not change anything from your code. i guess u must check out the frames of table view and the bottom view as everything else is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try capturing the event for  `UIControlEventTouchDown` instead of `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` in

`[self.signoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(signOutBtnTapped:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`;

Everything else seems OK.

Answer (score -1):

for Adding button in Footer view Section

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView* customView;

customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 60.0)];

UIButton *Login_Btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [Login_Btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_login.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Login_Btn.frame = kiPhoneButtonFrame;

[customView addSubview:Login_Btn];
[Login_Btn addTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(Login_Btn_Clicked:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return customView;
}
```

And Button Click Method

```
-(IBAction)Login_Btn_Clicked:(id)sender
{
     // Code for button CLick which you want to do.
}
```

Comment: in that case - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section; has also to be implemented, here the need is of a table footer instead of a section footer.

Comment: Then you can use  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section; In which just return (Hight of Footer section) Simple. There is simple thing to implement.